# Dynamic dates Pivot

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, pivot

Sample Data from StartKPA table:

[image]

I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT      *
FROM    
(
            SELECT BookInventoryDate, EndKpa,CASE WHEN (EndKPA*100)>80 THEN '>80' WHEN (EndKPA*100) BETWEEN 70 AND 80 THEN '70-80'
                                              WHEN (EndKPA*100) BETWEEN 65 AND 70 THEN '65-70'
                                              WHEN (EndKPA*100) BETWEEN 62 AND 65 THEN '62-65'
                                              WHEN (EndKPA*100) BETWEEN 60 AND 62 THEN '60-62'
                                              ELSE '<60' END as Aantallen
FROM        StartKPA
WHERE       BookInventoryDate > '20180429'
)           as Aantallen
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(EndKpa)
    FOR [BookInventoryDate] IN ([20180430], [20180501], [20180502])
) AS pvt
ORDER BY Aantallen DESC
```

With the following results (Sorry couldn't get in in a table here):

[image]

The problem is that I want dynamic dates. So every day a new date will be added, and the 20180502 isn't showed because there is no data. So I want the results in the above table, but everyday a new day will be added (and no zero results like above). I don't want to add a new date every day manually to the query.

There are some posts about it already, but I couldn't get it to work:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

;with cte (datelist, maxdate) as
(
select min(BookInventoryDate) datelist, max(BookinventoryDate) maxdate
from StartKPA
union all
select dateadd(dd, 1, datelist), maxdate
from cte
where datelist < maxdate
) 
select c.datelist
into #tempDates
from cte c

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(convert(CHAR(10), 
datelist, 120)) 
                from #tempDates
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT Aantallen, BookinventoryDate, ' + @cols + ' from 
         (
           SELECT BookInventoryDate, EndKpa,CASE WHEN (EndKPA*100)>80 THEN '>80' WHEN (EndKPA*100) BETWEEN 70 AND 80 THEN '70-80'
                                              WHEN (EndKPA*100) BETWEEN 65 AND 70 THEN '65-70'
                                              WHEN (EndKPA*100) BETWEEN 62 AND 65 THEN '62-65'
                                              WHEN (EndKPA*100) BETWEEN 60 AND 62 THEN '60-62'
                                              ELSE '<60' END as Aantallen
            FROM        #tempDates d
            LEFT JOIN   StartKPA kpa on d.datelist=kpa.bookinventorydate
            WHERE       BookInventoryDate > '20180429'
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            count(EndKpa)
            for PivotDate in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '

execute(@query)
```

I got a few error messages, tried to change things but I don't understand it enough to get it working.

Can someone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query. I was not able to check the query since I don't have data. If there is an error, please let me know.

`SELECT DISTINCT BookInventoryDate FROM StartKPA`

```
DECLARE @colsValues AS NVARCHAR(max) = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Quotename(datesYouWantAsColumns)
         FROM yourTable
         FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');
```

I'm getting unique dates assuming `StartKPA` is a table and `BookInventoryDate` is a field of that table. If'I'm wrong, please change it.

```
DECLARE @colsValues AS NVARCHAR(max) = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Quotename(BookInventoryDate)
         FROM StartKPA
         FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''); 

DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(max);

SET @query =   'SELECT      *
                FROM    
                (
                            SELECT BookInventoryDate, EndKpa,CASE WHEN (EndKPA*100)>80 THEN ''>80'' WHEN (EndKPA*100) BETWEEN 70 AND 80 THEN ''70-80''
                                                                WHEN (EndKPA*100) BETWEEN 65 AND 70 THEN ''65-70''
                                                                WHEN (EndKPA*100) BETWEEN 62 AND 65 THEN ''62-65''
                                                                WHEN (EndKPA*100) BETWEEN 60 AND 62 THEN ''60-62''
                                                                ELSE ''<60'' END as Aantallen
                FROM        StartKPA
                WHERE       BookInventoryDate > ''20180429''
                )           as Aantallen
                PIVOT
                (
                    COUNT(EndKpa)
                    FOR [BookInventoryDate] IN ('+ @colsValues +')
                ) AS pvt
                ORDER BY Aantallen DESC';

EXECUTE(@query);
```

Comment: Thanks for our input. I get the following error: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13 Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: Thanks, working now :-)! I added WHERE BookInventoryDate > '20180429' though in the first declare statement

Comment: @SqlUser, does your first query work? All I'm doing is getting the all unique dates columns for that query. So, you don't have to enter it manually. Look at the `FOR [BookInventoryDate] IN ('+ @colsValues +')` code.

Answer (score 1):

You should change single quotes `'`inside your @query by double single quotes `''`.

Keep in mind you're using a recursive query, you must set a correct value for:

```
OPTION (MAXRECURSION XXXX)
```

> ```
> create table StartKPA(BookInventoryDate datetime);
> insert into StartKPA values ('20180101'), ('20180108');
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 2 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
> @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
>
> ;with cte (datelist, maxdate) as
> (
> select min(BookInventoryDate) datelist, max(BookinventoryDate) maxdate
> from StartKPA
> union all
> select dateadd(dd, 1, datelist), maxdate
> from cte
> where datelist < maxdate
> ) 
> select c.datelist
> into #tempDates
> from cte c
> option (maxrecursion 0);
>
> select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(convert(CHAR(10), 
> datelist, 120)) 
>                 from #tempDates
>         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
>         ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
>     ,1,1,'')
>
> set @query = 'SELECT Aantallen, BookinventoryDate, ' + @cols + ' from 
>          (
>            SELECT BookInventoryDate, EndKpa,CASE WHEN (EndKPA*100)>80 THEN ''>80'' WHEN (EndKPA*100) BETWEEN 70 AND 80 THEN ''70-80''
>                                               WHEN (EndKPA*100) BETWEEN 65 AND 70 THEN ''65-70''
>                                               WHEN (EndKPA*100) BETWEEN 62 AND 65 THEN ''62-65''
>                                               WHEN (EndKPA*100) BETWEEN 60 AND 62 THEN ''60-62''
>                                               ELSE ''<60'' END as Aantallen
>             FROM        #tempDates d
>             LEFT JOIN   StartKPA kpa on d.datelist=kpa.bookinventorydate
>             WHERE       BookInventoryDate > ''20180429''
>         ) x
>         pivot 
>         (
>             count(EndKpa)
>             for PivotDate in (' + @cols + ')
>         ) p '
>
> select @query;
> GO
> ```

```
SELECT Aantallen, BookinventoryDate, [2018-01-01],[2018-01-02],[2018-01-03],[2018-01-04],[2018-01-05],[2018-01-06],[2018-01-07],[2018-01-08] from 
         (
           SELECT BookInventoryDate, EndKpa,CASE WHEN (EndKPA*100)>80 THEN '>80' WHEN (EndKPA*100) BETWEEN 70 AND 80 THEN '70-80'
                                              WHEN (EndKPA*100) BETWEEN 65 AND 70 THEN '65-70'
                                              WHEN (EndKPA*100) BETWEEN 62 AND 65 THEN '62-65'
                                              WHEN (EndKPA*100) BETWEEN 60 AND 62 THEN '60-62'
                                              ELSE '<60' END as Aantallen
            FROM        #tempDates d
            LEFT JOIN   StartKPA kpa on d.datelist=kpa.bookinventorydate
            WHERE       BookInventoryDate > '20180429'
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            count(EndKpa)
            for PivotDate in ([2018-01-01],[2018-01-02],[2018-01-03],[2018-01-04],[2018-01-05],[2018-01-06],[2018-01-07],[2018-01-08])
        ) p
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cbe467747ce48f06d0a05ef81499855c)*

Comment: Thanks! But I'm getting this error message: Msg 530, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Comment: You're using a recursive query, have a look at [OPTION (MAXRECURSION XXXX)](https://sqlwithmanoj.com/tag/option-maxrecursion/) I've added it to the answer.

Comment: Just having one last error I guess with the incorrect column name 'PivotDate' in the last query.

Comment: Instead of a picture of your current data, could you use my fiddle and add this data as INSERT statements?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not getting that fiddle

Comment: The link at end of the answer

Comment: Yes I opened that but am not really sure what to do with it. Sorry I'm not the most experienced person with this kind of stuff :)

Comment: simply change create table and inserts like : `insert into StartKPA values ('20180101'), ('20180108');`